# Compare two values from different dataframes and add values from one to other dataframe [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames in Pandas with following structure:

1. pr_df:

```
     id  prMerged  idRepository  avgTime
0     1      1           2         63.93
1     2      0           3         41.11
2     3      0           3         36.03
3     4      1           4         77.28
...
98   99      1           20        54.78   
99  100      0           20        42.12
```

2. repo_df

```
    id  stars   forks
0    1   1245     45
1    2   3689     78
2    3    458     15
3    4    954     75
...
19  20   1947    102
```

I would like to combine `pr_df` with `repo_df` by comparing `idRepository` (from pr_df) and `id` (from repo_df) with each other and add two columns to `pr_df`: `stars` and `forks`. As a result, I would like to achieve:

pr_df:

```
     id  prMerged  idRepository  avgTime   stars    forks
0     1      1           2         63.93    3689     78
1     2      0           3         41.11     458     15
2     3      0           3         36.03     458     15
3     4      1           4         77.28     954     75
...
98   99      1           20        54.78    1947     102
99  100      0           20        42.12    1947     102
```

How can I do it using Pandas? How can I compare `idRepository` with `id` and add new columns to `pr_df` based on that?

Comment: I think you might be looking for what's explained in the _"Different names for key columns"_ section of this other great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645883/289011

Answer (score 2):

You can use the merge function, and you have to supply the columns that you want to merge on.

```
pr_df.merge(repo_df, left_on='idRepository', right_on='id')
```